# How can I get into the Zookeeper that is integrated in Kafka? ( 2.2.0 )

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have installed a kafka that has integrated zookeeper.

I have seen that to enter an independent Zookeeper installation, you can run the following command to enter the zookeeper console:

```
bin/ZkCli.sh
ls /zookeeper/quota
```

But in Kafka's scripts I only have:

```
zookeeper-security-migration.sh
zookeeper-server-start.sh
zookeeper-server-stop.sh
zookeeper-shell.sh
```

I have tried to do the following:

```
./zookeeper-shell.sh -server 127.0.0.1:2181 ls /zookeeper/quota
```

But it doesn't work, it doesn't do anything

How can I get into the Zookeeper that is integrated in Kafka?

Comment: did you start the zookeeper first?

Comment: yes ( bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh -daemon config/zookeeper.properties )

Comment: What Kafka package did you install exactly ? anything relevant that could help in the config files ? Could you do a netstat -anop | grep 2181 on your box and show us the result ?

Comment: https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart <-- I have made the configuration here as an example. I started zookeper, kafka and created an example topic

Comment: tcp6       0      0 :::2181                 :::*                    ESCUCHAR    13136/java           apagado (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:56900         127.0.0.1:2181          ESTABLECIDO 13462/java           apagado (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:2181          127.0.0.1:56900         ESTABLECIDO 13136/java           apagado (0.00/0/0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After starting Zookeeper, you can connect to it using the `zookeeper-shell.sh` tool.

To get into the shell:

```
./zookeeper-shell IP:2181
```

Then you can execute commands, like:

```
ls /
```

You can use `cd` to move within the nodes and `get` to print the content of nodes.

You can also use this script to just run commands and return (without getting into the shell)

```
./zookeeper-shell.sh localhost:2181 get /controller
```

---

`/zookeeper/quota` is not a path used by Kafka, Quotas are stored under `/config`